# Python - Checking for "subdictionary"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary, key

```
A = {
    'a': 1,
    'b': 2,
    'c': 3
}

B = {
    'a': 1,
    'b': 2,
    'c': 3,
    'd': 4
}
```

My goal is to check whether A is a "subdictionary" of B. By that, I mean every pair of key:value in A is in B. Here's my try

```
def is_sub_dict(first_dict, second_dict):
    for x in first_dict:
        if x not in second_dict or first_dict[x] != second_dict[x]:
            return False
    return True

is_sub_dict(A, B) #True
is_sub_dict(B, A) #False
```

Is there a better way to do this? Or perhaps, a more pythonic way because this sure doesn't seem like it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

create a `set` from dict tuples then test if the set is a subset of the other item tuples

```
def is_subset(A,B):
   return set(A.items()).issubset(B.items())
```

Once created, `set` guarantees a very fast lookup.

(if the operation has to be repeated with the same `A` it's better to "cache" `set(A.items())` for better performance)

It works because values of the dictionaries are *hashable*. If they aren't, the good old `all(x in y for ...)` method is another option (see other answers).

Answer (score 5):

Check this out

```
all(item in B.items() for item in A.items())
```

Hope it will help you!!

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
def is_subset(a, b):
    return all(item in b for item in a)
```

And then simply:

```
if is_subset(A.items(), B.items()):
   # ...
```